# OSM iD editor WMS support

Tags: openstreetmap, wms, id-editor

I want to use my WMS layer as a background in OSM iD editor. I know it works in JOSM but I couldn't figure it out in iD editor. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: See also https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/40158/how-to-use-a-wms-layer-as-background-in-id-editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK iD currently doesn't support WMS but TMS protocol (press B key and add a custom TMS URL).

Thus you might deliver a tile map service instead of WMS or use a proxy (for example mapproxy).

Comment: can i still use map proxy (i don't know how to) without changing my WMS to TMS

Comment: mapproxy is a transparent solution to convert TMS request to request to your WMS backend. So yes you can use your existing server.

Answer (score 2):

iD now supports WMS since version 2.7.0 (March 2, 2018) (see https://github.com/openstreetmap/iD/issues/1141 and https://github.com/openstreetmap/openstreetmap-website/pull/1777).

However, there's isn't already support for custom WMS imagery (see https://github.com/openstreetmap/iD/issues/4977).
So to use WMS, you would have to use your own local iD installation.